# why is my javascript function not applying changes to my global variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, global

In javascript, I instantiated the global variable "sentimentValues" as follows:

```
var sentimentValues = [
    {txt: "good", num: 0},
    {txt: "bad", num: 0},
    {txt: "neutral", num: 0}
    ];
```

I later have a function in which the global variable "sentimentValues" is manipulated.
The function is as follows where data is an array created from csv file and each d is one entry in the csv file.

```
data.forEach(function(d){
            var strArray = d.message.split(" ");

            d.sentiment = calculateSentiment(strArray);
            if(d.sentiment == "good")
                sentimentValues[0].num += 1;
            else if(d.sentiment == "bad")
                sentimentValues[1].num += 1;
            else
                sentimentValues[2].num += 1;    
        })
```

Where "calculateSentiment" function is as follows:

```
    function calculateSentiment(wordArray)
    {
                var goodCount = 0;
                var badCount = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i<wordArray.length; i++)
                {
                    for(var index = 0; index<happyWords.length; index++)
                    {
                        if(happyWords[index] == wordArray[i])
                        {
                            goodCount++;
                        }
                    }

                    for(var index = 0; index<sadWords.length; index++)
                    {
                        if(sadWords[index] ==wordArray[i])
                            badCount++;
                    }
                }
                if(goodCount > badCount)
                    return "good";
                else if(badCount > goodCount)
                {
                    return "bad";
                }
                else
                    return "neutral";
    }
```

and happyWords, sadWords are defined as:

```
    var sadWords;
    var happyWords;

    $.get('happyWords.txt',function(data){
        happyWords = data.split('\n');
    });

    $.get('sadWords.txt',function(data){
        sadWords = data.split('\n');
    });
```

After the function is called, I call these two lines:

```
console.log(sentimentValues);
console.log(sentimentValues[0]);
```

the first log statement correctly reflects the changes made in the function (that is, sentimentValues[0].num is 2). the second log statement doesn't.

-the output in the console for the first statement expands to show sentimentValues[0].num to be 2 
-the output in the console for the second statement shows sentimentValues[0].num to be 0...

a screenshot of console output can be viewed here: http://lmc.gatech.edu/~epramer3/consoleOutput

What is happening here?

Comment: Could you please paste the *whole* code, including the function that manipulates the `values` array?

Comment: done. and I posted a link to a screenshot of the console (since I don't have enough reputation to include images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it would help if you paste more of your code, but first try to change the variable name "values".

Edit:
I checked your code and screenshot and even tried your code and the output came as expected.
It seems you are working on Google Chrome, did you try some simple steps like restarting the browser or trying another browser completely?

Comment: This doesn't qualify to be an answer and is merely a comment!

Comment: @LShetty He does not enough reputation to comment

Comment: and I don't have enough reputation to post a picture of the console :(  it's harder to describe than to show

Comment: @asakka, ugh I feel so silly. Firefox works -_- sometimes you forget about the little things...